# simulate a click of a href within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using javascript or jquery what would be the best way to simulate a click on live video inside div id 1.

Im not sure how to handle this when the `<a>` does not have a id attribute.

```
 <div id='1'>
       <a href="#" class="edit-settings">Edit Settings</a>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="live_video">Live Video</a>
 </div>

 <div id='2'>
       <a href="#" class="edit-settings">Edit Settings</a>
       <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="live_video">Live Video</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Note that using jQuery to `trigger` the event will not follow the `href` property for an `<a>` (probably what you want), while triggering the DOM `click` event will

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger the click on the first link.

```
$("#1 > a:first").trigger('click');
```

To trigger the click on the second link.

```
$("#1 > a:last").trigger('click');
```

You do have CSS classes you can use as well.

```
$("#1 > a.live_view").trigger('click');
```

NOTE: a DOM ID can not start with a number.

Comment: `trigger('click')` can be changed to `click()`

Comment: so in order to use the name live_video i need to use the a.live_video correct?

Comment: @tman that is correct. `live_video` is a CSS class. You use a dot to reference a class.

Comment: perfect Thanks for the note on the DOM ID aswell :) thanks will accept!

Comment: any idea how to do this exact line in javascript aswell `$("#1 > a.live_view").trigger('click');`

Comment: No clue. I live and breath jQuery to the point that I have lost my virgin abilities with the DOM.

Comment: lol fine fine `$('#iFrameID').contents().find('??????').click(); ` could  i replace the ????? with `"#1 > a.live_view"` then ?

Comment: @tman All DOM ID selectors are explicit. There is no ancestry search performed. So $("#my_id") will go straight to that DOM cause the ID is unique. The rest of the selector is from that ID. So `#a1 > a.live_view` will work if the unique ID is "a1"

Comment: HTML5 allows `id`s to start with (and be) numbers

Comment: @Ian oh no, let the horror begin. Next thing you know people will be using just an underscore as the ID.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini My point was that `NOTE: a DOM ID can not start with a number` is not correct. I never said whether it was a good idea to use it, or as you mention, underscores. If you want to suggest a "best practice" or reasons why they should/shouldn't, do that

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('2').getElementsByClassName('live_video')[0].click();
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/christianheinrichs/tozr2jbn/2/) is a working jsFiddle

I updated it so it answers the following question:

> thanks for your edit is there away to specify the a href by the class rather then childnodes – tman

Comment: this does not select by the div id which is important.

Comment: thanks for your edit is there away to specify the a href by the class rather then childnodes

Comment: Although this won't work **because** `.childNodes[0]` will return a text node (since there is whitespace in the element), not the `<a>`. `.children[0]` could be used in place